# Discord.js create Channel Invite

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a invite to a specific textchannel, while i'm trying to create the Invite via the createInvite function, it throws me the Error:

`TypeError: picchannel.createInvite is not a function`

My Code:

```
 picchannel = client.channels.fetch("1205625326290608179")
 if (message.channel != picchannel) {
       if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
           //message.reply(picmsgs.random())
           const invite = picchannel.createInvite({})
           message.reply(invite)
       }
  }
```

i already tried the promise, did also not work for me.

The picchannel variable is set correct and does work, so thats also not the problem.